# Custom Pipe with checkbox doesn't give correct value

Tags: angular

So i'm trying to implement into my angular projdct a custom pipe that i use to filter data that comes from *NgFor, it works all and good with a input of type text, but when i do a checkbox it doesn't seem to work. It just hides all my products. I believe its because there is no value passed by a checkbock ? How can i make this work ? Should change how my pipe work ?

**NOTE** : I'm speaking only about the First checkbox that is [(ngModel)] = "cotton"

**material.pipe.ts**

```
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'material',
  pure: false
})
export class MaterialPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(values: any, args?: any): any {
   return args ? values.filter(product => product.material === args) : values;
  }

}
```

**product-list.component.html**

```
<div class="category-container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Material</h2>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="cotton" value="Cotton" name="Cotton">
      <label for="defaultCheck1" class="form-check-label">
        Cotton
      </label>
      <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="silk" (change)="loadProductsSecond()">
      <label for="defaultCheck1" class="form-check-label">
        Silk
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <div *ngFor="let product of products | material: cotton"  class="col-6">
      <app-product-card [product]="product" ></app-product-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**product-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ProductService } from 'src/app/_services/product.service';
import { Product } from 'src/app/_models/product';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-list',
  templateUrl: './product-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-list.component.css']
})
export class ProductListComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() product: Product;
  products: Product[];
  cotton: any;
  silk: any;
  filter1 = 'Cotton';
  filter2 = 'Silk';
  constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadProducts();
  }

  loadProducts() {
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe((products: Product[]) => {
      this.products = products;
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

**Data of products**
Note that i used random values that might not be in english.
But both the english ones and the none english ones work with the Input of type text, but not with the input of type checkbox.

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Цвете",
    "category": "Празничен",
    "material": "Памук и Вълна",
    "size": "25cm",
    "price": 10.5,
    "description": "Тест Тест",
    "referenceNumber": "123123SY"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "тест",
    "category": "тес",
    "material": "тес",
    "size": "тест",
    "price": 11,
    "description": "тесте",
    "referenceNumber": "454545TY"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Test",
    "category": "Test",
    "material": "Test",
    "size": "Test",
    "price": 23.35,
    "description": "fgdfgwertwer",
    "referenceNumber": "64562XY"
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Secret Toymaker2",
    "category": "сдфгсдфг",
    "material": "Cotton",
    "size": "25cm",
    "price": 10.5,
    "description": "asdqwe",
    "referenceNumber": "1231ss23SY"
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Кошничка",
    "category": "Поднос",
    "material": "Прежда",
    "size": "20см",
    "price": 5.5,
    "description": "Хубава кошничка за държане на предмети.",
    "referenceNumber": "56712RV"
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "name": null,
    "category": null,
    "material": null,
    "size": null,
    "price": 0,
    "description": null,
    "referenceNumber": null
},
{
    "id": 7,
    "name": "asdasd",
    "category": "gsadfsdf",
    "material": "Прежда",
    "size": "123cm",
    "price": 12,
    "description": "dfgsdfgretert",
    "referenceNumber": "12312515XY"
}
```

]

Thanks in advance ! :]

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz that reproduces your problem? Also, why did you set your pipe not `pure`?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner i'm using a .net Core back-end that takes the products from a database. So it might be a bit hard to replicate what is happening. Also i forgot to remove that, i was trying different ways to fix it and i was checking if setting it to not pure would help. But it is the same issue both ways.

Comment: At least, can you post an example of your json data?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner I included in the main-post the data i have.
The data itself is kind of random just for testing outside of the material, which is more specific for the testing purposes.

Comment: do you wan't to check both check box at the same time or make them act them like radio? . Ether way,  the above code is wrong as you are not passing the check box value to the pipe , instead you are just passing true or false . you can check the same by `console.log(args)` in the pipe

Comment: also  you need to listen to  change event of the checkbox  `(change)="onCheck($event)"` and  write necessary logic  to that function

Comment: @JoelJoseph Thanks for the input. I think this has cleared some weather now. Also yes i am trying to check both at the same time. But i didn't really mention it as i have yet to make 1 work.

Comment: @JoelJoseph Since i made it work after making the onCheck function on the change event. What should i configure in the pipe in such cases to listen to mulptiple arguments ? Since i would like to add more checkboxes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working Solution  [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eebygh).

You have to make  following changes in your code  :

**material.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'material',
  pure: false
})
export class MaterialPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(array: any, query: string[]): any[] {
    if (typeof array === 'object') {
      var resultArray = [];
      if (query.length === 0) {
        resultArray = array;
      }
      else {
        resultArray = (array.filter(function (a) {
          return ~this.indexOf(a.material);
        }, query));
      }
      return resultArray;
    }
    else {
      return null;
    }
  }

}
```

**product-list.component.html**

```
<div class="category-container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h2>Material</h2>
    <div class="form-check">
      <input type="checkbox" (change)="onCheck($event, 'Cotton')"   value="Cotton" name="Cotton">
      <label for="defaultCheck1" class="form-check-label">
        Cotton
      </label>
      <input (change)="onCheck($event,'silk')"  type="checkbox"   value="silk">
      <label for="defaultCheck1" class="form-check-label">
        Silk
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row align-items-start">
    <div *ngFor="let product of products | material: filterKeys"  class="col-6">
      {{ product?.name }} |   {{ product?.material }}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**product-list.component.ts**

```
products= [
      {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Цвете",
          "category": "Празничен",
          "material": "Памук и Вълна",
          "size": "25cm",
          "price": 10.5,
          "description": "Тест Тест",
          "referenceNumber": "123123SY"
      },
      {
          "id": 2,
          "name": "тест",
          "category": "тес",
          "material": "silk",
          "size": "тест",
          "price": 11,
          "description": "тесте",
          "referenceNumber": "454545TY"
      },
      {
          "id": 3,
          "name": "Test",
          "category": "Test",
          "material": "Test",
          "size": "Test",
          "price": 23.35,
          "description": "fgdfgwertwer",
          "referenceNumber": "64562XY"
      },
      {
          "id": 4,
          "name": "Secret Toymaker2",
          "category": "сдфгсдфг",
          "material": "Cotton",
          "size": "25cm",
          "price": 10.5,
          "description": "asdqwe",
          "referenceNumber": "1231ss23SY"
      },
      {
          "id": 5,
          "name": "Кошничка",
          "category": "Поднос",
          "material": "Прежда",
          "size": "20см",
          "price": 5.5,
          "description": "Хубава кошничка за държане на предмети.",
          "referenceNumber": "56712RV"
      },
      {
          "id": 6,
          "name": null,
          "category": null,
          "material": null,
          "size": null,
          "price": 0,
          "description": null,
          "referenceNumber": null
      },
      {
          "id": 7,
          "name": "asdasd",
          "category": "gsadfsdf",
          "material": "Прежда",
          "size": "123cm",
          "price": 12,
          "description": "dfgsdfgretert",
          "referenceNumber": "12312515XY"
      }
    ];

  filterKeyWord: string = '';
  filterKeys = [];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onCheck(event, $value) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.filterKeys.push($value);
    }
    else {
      this.filterKeys.splice(this.filterKeys.indexOf($value), 1);
    }

    if (this.filterKeys.length > 0) {
      this.filterKeyWord = this.filterKeys.join();
      console.log(this.filterKeyWord);
    }
    else {
      this.filterKeyWord = '';
    }

  }
```

Comment: Looking at your answer and the way i made it work.. Your way is so much better and logical. Gives me better idea at how pipe should work. Thanks a lot!